# Doxygen: Force undeclared functions to be documented

Tags: doxygen

Our C++ program has a built-in script interface and is able to run scripts in it. The scripts have access to convenience functions provided by the C++ program.

Now we would like Doxygen to create the documentation of the functions the script has access to. Such a function declaration looks like this:

```
void ScriptEngine::load_script(const QString &path) {       
//...

    /*! \fn sleep_ms(const unsigned int timeout_ms)
        \brief sleeps for timeout_ms milliseconds.
        \param timeout_ms 
    */
    (*lua)["sleep_ms"] = [](const unsigned int timeout_ms) {
        //sleep(timeout_ms)
    };

    //more convenience functions..
//...
}
```

Obviously Doxygen won't include a

`sleep_ms(const unsigned int timeout_ms)`

into the documentation. Is there a way to to tell Doxygen to do so?

Comment: Possibility that I see is to create a prototype of the function and document it.

Comment: yes, I already tried this.       
<code>
    void ScriptEngine::load_script(const QString &path) {       
    
    //...


    /*! \fn sleep_ms(const unsigned int timeout_ms)
        \brief sleeps for timeout_ms milliseconds.
        \param timeout_ms 
    */ 
    void sleep_ms(const unsigned int timeout_ms);
     
    
    },
</code>
But since the prototype is placed within the function ScriptEngine::load_script the function  sleep_ms is ignored by Doxygen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

1. Add the following line to your Doxyfile:

   ```
   PREDEFINED = _DOXYGEN_
   ```
2. Make sure the `ENABLE_PREPROCESSING` tag in the Doxyfile is set to `YES`.
3. Put your declarations and documentation for the undeclared functions inside an `#ifdef _DOXYGEN_` section.

   ```
   #ifdef _DOXYGEN_
       /*! \fn sleep_ms(const unsigned int timeout_ms) 
           \brief sleeps for timeout_ms milliseconds.
           \param timeout_ms
       */
       void sleep_ms(const unsigned int timeout_ms);
   #endif
   ```

Don't put the above code inside a method or function such as `ScriptEngine::load_script()`, as you previously tried. And don't put it inside a namespace or class, unless in fact the function being declared is a member of that namespace or class.

With this method, your declarations will not create linker errors during a normal build, but will be seen by Doxygen.

**See Also**

http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_predefined