# Doxygen list undeclared functions

Tags: assembly, doxygen

I want to document assembly code with Doxygen and my idea is that I define assembly functions with \fn. But Doxygen won't list those functions because it can't find the declaration.

I found this thread [Doxygen: Force undeclared functions to be documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510536/doxygen-force-undeclared-functions-to-be-documented) but I can't declare that C-Function because if I do that my assembler won't assembly my file. Is there a way to force Doxygen to list functions documented with \fn although they are not declared?

Example-Code:

```
/*
 * \fn void pinSetup(int pin)
 *
 * \param pin   pin number
 */
pinSetup:
    mov r1, r0
    ...
```

Comment: Keep in mind that assembly doesn't have functions, only labels.

Comment: I know. My intention is to make calls to those labels and handling them those like functions. Our team wants to document them as functions were the function parameters are passed by registers and stack

Comment: The answer to the question you linked should work if you preprocess your assembly files, eg. with `gcc -c filename.S` or `gcc -c -x assembler-with-cpp filename.s` or if you're not using GNU assembler syntax `gcc -E -x c filename.asm > filename.i && asm filename.i` where `asm` is the name of the assembler you're using.  Well, that is assuming Doxygen can parse a C declaration randomly inserted into in the middle of a bunch of assembly statements.

Answer (score 0):

A trick is to expose more "code" to doxygen than to the compiler.

For example, define a dummy define, always true when building with doxygen:

```
PREDEFINED = IN_DOXYGEN
```

And in some C code, add a fake function like this:

```
#ifdef IN_DOXYGEN
/**
  Doc for pinSetup.
  @param pin   pin number
*/
void pinSetup(int pin) { /* Implemented in asm */ }
#endif /* IN_DOXYGEN */
```